# MYSQL TIME without seconds

Tags: php, mysql

In PHPmyAdmin I stored times with TIME function.
They are displayed as hh:mm:ss.
With PHP I want to remove the seconds and use following script:

```
$startTime = $row["open"];
$print_time = date("H:i", strtotime($startTime));
```

It returnes "01:00", the seconds are removed, but the time should display "11:50" or "14:17", per example.

Comment: What is the value of `$startTime`?

Comment: if `$startTime` value is a timestamp remove `strtotime()` function call.

Comment: $startTime value is 06:00:00

Comment: Yes, it is a timestamp, but removing strtotime() returns 01:00

Comment: @ROOT When you fetch timestamps they're returned as a formatted datetime, not numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date("H:i", strtotime($startTime));` returns `'01:00'` when `strtotime($startTime)` returns a value 0-60.

`strtotime($startTime);` returns `false` (0) when `$startTime` doesn't match a valid time format as described at https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php.

```
$startTime = '06:00:00';
$print_time = date("H:i", strtotime($startTime));
var_dump($print_time);
```

outputs `string(5) "06:00"`

```
$startTime = 'invalidformat'; // E.g. $startTime = false;
$print_time = date("H:i", strtotime($startTime)); // strtotime($startTime) returns false
var_dump($print_time);
```

outputs `string(5) "01:00"`

Please double check the value of `$startTime`.
E.g. `var_dump($startTime);`

Comment: Thank you very much!